# Green function for first order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

What is the green function for:

$$\frac{\partial u }{\partial t}-\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}-\delta \left ( x \right )u=f(x,t)$$
Initial condition is zero and boundary condition is zero at infinity. The domain is from 0 to +$\infty$.
I got Laplace transform first to get:
$$su-\frac{\partial u }{\partial x}-\delta \left ( x \right )u=\delta \left ( x-\zeta  \right )e^{-s\tau }$$

Comment: Please state what you have tried so far. What did you get stuck on?

Comment: I got the Laplace transform and then getting Fourier transform. what is Fourier transform of delta*u?

Comment: Update the question to reflect what you have done so far.

Comment: I updated that. I think I need to use convolution for Fourier transform. Not sure

Comment: Are you sure about the PDE? If yes, how should $\delta(x) u$ be interpreted?

Comment: Yes, I am sure of that. This PDE is not an independent PDE, it is part of the solution for another PDE.